# Are Object Limits available from a Salesforce API?

Tags: api, governorlimits, object

When in Object Manager, there is '[Object Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_standard_objects_limits_page.htm&type=5)'; which displays the high-level limit info of that particular object.

It would be helpful to be able to query this via a Salesforce API.

It seems that this isn't possible (and it's the same story with Company Information).

I wanted to check if this indeed is not possible via the API? I haven't found any documentation to suggest that it is.

*Some* of these limits could be calculated using Schema Describe logic or using other approaches but that hopefully, there's a nicer way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have access to 'Object Limits' of an object by '[EntityLimit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitylimit.htm)' which is a [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) object.

You can do a query to your org, using the Tooling API. An example for the object 'Account' would be:

```
curl https://yourInstanceUrl.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+DurableId,+Type,+Label,+Max,+Remaining,+EntityDefinitionId+FROM+EntityLimit+WHERE+EntityDefinitionId+=+\'Account\' -H 'Authorization: Bearer yourToken' -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1'
```

The response will be very similar to this one, you can parse it and take whatever you need:

```
{
  "size" : 11,
  "totalSize" : 11,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "EntityLimit",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CustomFields"
    },
    "Type" : "CustomFields",
    "Label" : "Custom Fields",
    "Remaining" : 246,
    "Max" : 500,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.RollupSummary"
    },
    "Type" : "RollupSummary",
    "Label" : "Rollup Summary Fields",
    "Remaining" : 24,
    "Max" : 25,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CustomRelationship"
    },
    "Type" : "CustomRelationship",
    "Label" : "Custom Relationship Fields",
    "Remaining" : 20,
    "Max" : 40,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveRules"
    },
    "Type" : "ActiveRules",
    "Label" : "Active Workflow Rules",
    "Remaining" : 50,
    "Max" : 50,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.TotalRules"
    },
    "Type" : "TotalRules",
    "Label" : "Total Workflow Rules",
    "Remaining" : 500,
    "Max" : 500,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ApprovalProcesses"
    },
    "Type" : "ApprovalProcesses",
    "Label" : "Approval Processes",
    "Remaining" : 500,
    "Max" : 500,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveLookupFilters"
    },
    "Type" : "ActiveLookupFilters",
    "Label" : "Active Lookup Filters",
    "Remaining" : 3,
    "Max" : 5,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveValidationRules"
    },
    "Type" : "ActiveValidationRules",
    "Label" : "Active Validation Rules",
    "Remaining" : 100,
    "Max" : 100,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.VLookup"
    },
    "Type" : "VLookup",
    "Label" : "VLOOKUP Functions",
    "Remaining" : 10,
    "Max" : 10,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.SharingRules"
    },
    "Type" : "SharingRules",
    "Label" : "Sharing Rules (Both Owner- and Criteria-based)",
    "Remaining" : 288,
    "Max" : 300,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "EntityLimit",
      "url" : "/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CbsSharingRules"
    },
    "Type" : "CbsSharingRules",
    "Label" : "Sharing Rules (Criteria-based Only)",
    "Remaining" : 40,
    "Max" : 50,
    "EntityDefinitionId" : "Account"
  } ]
}
```